# MySQL slow execution of IN query with PREPARE STATEMENT after upgrading from 5.7.28 to 8.0.27

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

Here's the technology stack I'm using,
Java 11, JOOQ 3.12.1 and MYSQL 8.0.28 ( upgraded from 5.7.28 ) with connection pooling(30) and engine InnoDB.

Here's the example query I've successfully executed with use of JOOQ within 1s in MySQL 5.7.28. IN query takes about 60k IDs. Now MYSQL 8.0.28 takes around 92s for this query.

```
select `id`, `name`, `description` from `ex_table` where `id` in (?,?,?,?,?,....);
```

Just for the information I've used mariadb and mysql connector both so I can conclude that there isn't the issue with the connector.

[EDIT]

```
show create table ex_table;
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ex_table | CREATE TABLE `ex_table` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stack_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_node` (`name`,`stack_id`),
  KEY `idx_stack` (`stack_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72279 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)



SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'ex_table';
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name       | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| ex_table | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 60272 |             43 |     2637824 |               0 |      5275648 |   4194304 |          72279 | 2022-06-30 07:10:14 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)



explain select `id`, `name`, `description`, `stack_id` from `ex_table` where `id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ex_table | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   10 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)




Running Full Query with Explain:

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ex_table | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 60272 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.51 sec)
```

SLOW QUERY LOG

```
# Time: 2022-07-18T14:38:02.110872-00:00
# User@Host: user[host] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Schema: dbname  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 33.762935  Lock_time: 0.075141  Rows_sent: 60052  Rows_examined: 60052  Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 1619164
use dbname;
SET timestamp=1658155048;
select `dbname`.`ex_table`.`id`, `dbname`.`ex_table`.`name`, `dbname`.`ex_table`.`description`, `dbname`.`ex_table`.`stack_id` from `dbname`.`ex_table` where `dbname`.`ex_table`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, ... );
```

**[edit 2]**
Optimiser Trace

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "statement_parameters": [
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
        "LONGLONG",
         ……,
    …..,
      ]
    },
    {
      "join_optimization": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "condition_processing": {
              "condition": "WHERE",
              "original_condition": "(`ex_table`.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101, …))”,
              "steps": [
                {
                  "transformation": "equality_propagation",
                  "resulting_condition": "(`ex_table `.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,…))”
                },
                {
                  "transformation": "trivial_condition_removal",
                  "resulting_condition": "(`ex_table `.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,…))”,
                "final_table_condition   ": "(`ex_table`.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,..))”
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "refine_plan": [
              {
                "table": "`ex_table`”
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_execution": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Explain format=json SELECT ...

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "6047.05"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": “ex_table”,
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 60068,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 30034,
      "filtered": "50.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "3043.65",
        "eval_cost": "3003.40",
        "prefix_cost": "6047.05",
        "data_read_per_join": "108M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        “stack”_id
      ],
      "attached_condition": "(`db`.`ex_table`.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,….))”
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you compared the plans (i.e. explain)? Are the statistics up to date?

Comment: I think there may be a database setting that affects how long of an IN list you can have before it decides a full table scan is the better choice, but I don't remember what it is.  even without that, doing `from ex_table force index (PRIMARY) where` may help, I'm not sure.  do do an explain in the new and (if you can) old versions to check what it is actually trying, though.

Comment: To answer both the questions, yes I've checked the statistics and it's up to date and have tried with force index as well but no luck with that

Comment: I'm not finding the setting I remember.  Try joining instead: `select id,name,description from (select null id where 0 union all values row(?),row(?),row(?),row(?)) ids join ex_table using (id)`

Comment: Thanks @ysth for the reply and looking for the database setting. Actually I don't have any other option then finding the reason & resolving this query itself. It's the big enterprise system and this is one query from it.

Comment: So after our conversation I've tried with rewriteBatchedsStatements flag on and it worked wonders but again as per diff forums we can't trust the result when this flag in on so this option is out as well

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOw CREATE TABLE ex_table; B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'ex_table';  and C) your SELECT query including the FIRST 10 IN values sent to the optimizer  and D) EXPLAIN SELECT ..... rest of your query for 60K id's.

Comment: So you build a literal list of 60k elements? Why do you need to do that in the first place?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added what you asked for in the question. Please note that when I execute the last query without prepare because it's not easy to generate 60k variables on prepare and run manually.

Comment: @Olivier I know that's the wrong practice but this was working in mysql 5.7. It's strange that after upgrading to mysql v8 it drastically reduced the performance. This is the one of the example of the query. There may be other queries like this as well

Comment: There's nothing strange. When upgrading a database (and you have a big upgrade here), sometimes it happens that some queries (especially poorly written queries) are not optimized anymore. Either rewrite the query properly or don't upgrade the server.

Comment: Where did the ids come from?  You might be able get rid of this query if you JOINed rather than collecting ids, then doing this query.

Comment: The network cost of sending 60K result rows probably outweighs the slowness of the full table scan?

Comment: The network cost of sending 60K result rows probably outweighs the slowness of the full table scan? 60K seems to be most of the table. In that case using the index will slow down the query.

Comment: Have you ruled out caching, network changes, etc?

Comment: @RickJames I would be definitely changing the query on the later release but I don't have any other choice left beside working out the solution for the current one. And yes Rick I've system running with both the setup with same network and same mysql variables but the later one is taking ~92s

Comment: Just for the information, this query did executed withing ~0.5s when there was ~1L records in v5.7 database.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ... ` and, if practical, get the "Optimizer Trace".  Preferrably for both servers, but at least for 8.0.

Comment: The 0.5s for 100K rows seems reasonable; the 92 seems _very_ unreasonable.  Is the timing made from Java?  I assume you reran it and got a similar value?  If the slowlog was on, what did it record about the query?  If not on, please turn it on and rerun.

Comment: @RickJames I've edited my question with slowlog and regarding you question with java, No java and db connection client sends the query to mysql but mysql is taking time to execute parameterized queries. Something weird with replacing (?, ?, ..)  with the list of IDs

Comment: Because the strange thing is that, when I execute IN directly with IDs it executes within a second on mysql 8 but when mysql prepares the parameterized queries from its end it takes ~92s

Comment: If you have determined that the 'binding' is the slow part, self-answer your question, showing the Java code and explaining that it is the slow part.  (You deserve the bounty.)

Comment: @RickJames Nothing wrong with the JAVA end. Java successfully passes the query to execute to mysql but in the end mysql is taking time for sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246545/discussion-between-aniket-pawar-and-rick-james).

Comment: Hmmm... 33.8s -- not as bad as 92, but still really bad.  This presumably does not include the "binding".

Comment: @RickJames I've edited the question with results of EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ... and "Optimizer Trace for mysql 8".

Comment: Did you review any changes in settings between the two versions?

Comment: Yes, most of them are same. Few extra settings added by 8 but nothing related to particular this problem.

Comment: What is result of SELECT @@in_predicate_conversion_threshold; ?  Your version may NOT have this Global Variable.  Also what is your result of SELECT @@version: ?

Comment: Fetching 60052 rows and shoveling them across the network takes time.  Why so many?  Did you really have 60052 ids in the list?  Or is `id` not the `PRIMARY KEY`?  On the other hand, only 1.6MB was returned.

Comment: Does JOOQ receive only 1 row at a time.  (Most products receive the whole resultset in a single gulp.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck - `in_predicate_conversion_threshold` was introduced in MariaDB 10.3.18; it was never (yet) in 5.7 or 8.0.  Too bad; it might be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this before, mainly because of the difference between the two versions of query optimizer, and of course it's related to several parameters of innodb.