# Poor Performance on Specific Queries after MySQL 8.0 Upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

EDIT: I am seeing the same behavior in Python as PHP. Seems to be something with MySQL.

We are trying to upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0. Our codebase uses PHP MySQLi for queries to our MySQL server. In our test setups, we are seeing poorer performance (50x slower) on certain queries that bind lots of parameters. We want to see MySQL 8.0 run in similar time as 5.7. Below is the example table structure and trouble query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `name_id` (`id`,`name`) USING BTREE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uniquevalue` (`a_id`,`value`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `a_id` (`a_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `v` (`value`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c` (
  `product` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `b_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product`,`b_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `b_id` (`b_id`),
  KEY `product` (`product`),
  CONSTRAINT `c_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

```sql
-- example trouble query
SELECT c.product, a.name, b.value
FROM b
INNER JOIN a ON b.a_id = a.id AND a.name IN ('1be6f9eb563f3bf85c78b4219bf09de9')
-- this hash is from the dataset (linked below) but it should match a record in the 'a' table that has an associated record in the 'b' table that in turn has an associated record in the 'c' table
INNER JOIN c on c.b_id = b.id and c.product IN (?, ?, ?...) -- ... meaning dynamic number of parameters
```

If the query is modified to only return one record (limit 1), the query is still slow. So it isn't about the volume of data being returned. If the query is ran non-parameterized (with string concatenation), query run time is acceptable in all environments. The more parameters you add, the slower the query gets (linear). With 7,000 bound parameters, the query runs in 100 - 150 ms in MySQL 5.7 and ~10 seconds in MySQL 8.0.28. We see the same results in PHP 7.4 and 8.0. We see the same results with MySQLi or PDO.

This tells me that it is something to do with parameter binding. I enabled profiling and checked the results for the query. The bulk of the query's time (~95%) was spent in the execution step, not the parameter binding step. Also, I see mysql 8 process CPU is pegged while query is running. I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Here is the explain for MySQL 8.0.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | const | PRIMARY,name,name_id | name | 1022 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c |  | ref | PRIMARY,b_id,product | product | 152 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,uniquevalue,a_id | PRIMARY | 4 | DefaultWeb.c.b_id | 1 | 5 | Using where |

Here is the explain for MySQL 5.7.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | const | PRIMARY,name,name_id | name | 257 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c |  | ref | PRIMARY,b_id,product | PRIMARY | 152 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,uniquevalue,a_id | PRIMARY | 4 | DefaultWeb.c.b_id | 1 | 5 | Using where |

There are some differences between these two explains, but once again this problem only occurs with prepared statements within PHP.

Below is some php code demonstrating the problem. This code is written to work against the dataset I've provided in the Google Drive link below. I've also included our MySQL variables in a CSV.

```php
<?php
// Modify these to fit your DB connection.
const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const USER = 'root';
const PASS = 'localtest';
const DB_NAME = 'TestDatabase';

// As the number of parameters increases, time increases linearly.
// We're seeing ~10 seconds with 7000 params with this data.
const NUM_PARAMS = 7000;

function rand_string($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function sql_question_marks($count, $sets = 1) {
    return substr(str_repeat(",(".substr(str_repeat(",?", $count), 1).")", $sets), 1);
}

function unsecure_concat($params) {
    return "('" . implode("','", $params) . "')";
}

$params = [];
$param_types = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < NUM_PARAMS; $i++) {
    $params[] = rand_string();
    $param_types .= 's';
}

$big_query = <<<SQL
    SELECT c.product, a.name, b.value
    FROM b
    INNER JOIN a ON b.a_id = a.id AND a.name IN ('1be6f9eb563f3bf85c78b4219bf09de9')
    INNER JOIN c on c.b_id = b.id and c.product IN
SQL . sql_question_marks(count($params));

$non_parameterized = <<<SQL
    SELECT c.product, a.name, b.value
    FROM b
    INNER JOIN a ON b.a_id = a.id AND a.name IN ('1be6f9eb563f3bf85c78b4219bf09de9')
    INNER JOIN c on c.b_id = b.id and c.product IN
SQL . unsecure_concat($params);

$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB_NAME);

$q = $connection->prepare($big_query);
$q->bind_param($param_types, ...$params);
$start_time = hrtime(true);
$q->execute(); // This one shows the issue...100-250 ms execution time in MySQL 5.7 and ~10 seconds with 8.0.
$end_time = hrtime(true);

$total_time = ($end_time - $start_time) / 1000000000; // convert to seconds

echo 'The total time for parameterized query is ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';

$q->get_result(); // not concerned with results.

$q = $connection->prepare($big_query . ' LIMIT 1');
$q->bind_param($param_types, ...$params);
$start_time = hrtime(true);
$q->execute(); // This one also shows the issue...100-250 ms execution time in MySQL 5.7 and ~10 seconds with 8.0.
$end_time = hrtime(true);

$total_time = ($end_time - $start_time) / 1000000000; // convert to seconds

echo '<br>The total time for parameterized query with limit 1 is ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';

$q->get_result(); // not concerned with results 

$q = $connection->prepare($non_parameterized);
$start_time = hrtime(true);
$q->execute(); // Same execution time in 5.7 and 8.0.
$end_time = hrtime(true);

$total_time = ($end_time - $start_time) / 1000000000; // convert to seconds

echo '<br>The total time for non-parameterized query is ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';
```

You can download example data here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/111T7g1NowfWO_uZ2AhT9jdj4LiSNck8u/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: Here is the JSON explain with 7,000 bound parameters.

```json
{
    "EXPLAIN": {
        "query_block": {
            "select_id": 1,
            "cost_info": {
                "query_cost": "456.60"
            },
            "nested_loop": [
                {
                    "table": {
                        "table_name": "a",
                        "access_type": "const",
                        "possible_keys": [
                            "PRIMARY",
                            "name",
                            "name_id"
                        ],
                        "key": "name",
                        "used_key_parts": [
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "key_length": "257",
                        "ref": [
                            "const"
                        ],
                        "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
                        "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
                        "filtered": "100.00",
                        "using_index": true,
                        "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "0.00",
                            "eval_cost": "0.10",
                            "prefix_cost": "0.00",
                            "data_read_per_join": "264"
                        },
                        "used_columns": [
                            "id",
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "table": {
                        "table_name": "b",
                        "access_type": "ref",
                        "possible_keys": [
                            "PRIMARY",
                            "uniquevalue",
                            "a_id"
                        ],
                        "key": "uniquevalue",
                        "used_key_parts": [
                            "a_id"
                        ],
                        "key_length": "4",
                        "ref": [
                            "const"
                        ],
                        "rows_examined_per_scan": 87,
                        "rows_produced_per_join": 87,
                        "filtered": "100.00",
                        "using_index": true,
                        "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "8.44",
                            "eval_cost": "8.70",
                            "prefix_cost": "17.14",
                            "data_read_per_join": "65K"
                        },
                        "used_columns": [
                            "id",
                            "a_id",
                            "value"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "table": {
                        "table_name": "c",
                        "access_type": "ref",
                        "possible_keys": [
                            "PRIMARY",
                            "b_id",
                            "product"
                        ],
                        "key": "b_id",
                        "used_key_parts": [
                            "b_id"
                        ],
                        "key_length": "4",
                        "ref": [
                            "TestDatabase.b.id"
                        ],
                        "rows_examined_per_scan": 35,
                        "rows_produced_per_join": 564,
                        "filtered": "18.28",
                        "using_index": true,
                        "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "130.53",
                            "eval_cost": "56.47",
                            "prefix_cost": "456.60",
                            "data_read_per_join": "88K"
                        },
                        "used_columns": [
                            "product",
                            "b_id"
                        ],
                        "attached_condition": "" // i've omitted the condition since it breaks the SO char limit, it contains 7,000 random character strings at 10 length each
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the EXPLAINs to the original post. Also yes, fewer items in the IN will result in less time, we are observing a completely linear relationship. To an extent this makes sense and is expected, but 5.7 was able to execute these large prepared statements in roughly 1/50th the time that 8.0 can.

Comment: In MySQL 8, the default character set is `utf8mb4`, which allows 4 bytes per character.  Thus, your key field went from 257 to 1022.  You might try specifying a character set for the `name` field in your table `a`.

Comment: Specifying the character set for the `name` field does indeed reduce the key length back down to 257. However, unfortunately it has no effect on this query's execution time when parameterized.

Comment: @WormyGels  With this detail of yours 'There are some differences between these two explains, but once again this problem only occurs with prepared statements within PHP.' please consider posting each of your prepared statement code and the options used when the PREPARE(s) is/are completed to enable the use of the prepared statement(s).

Comment: @WilsonHauck The prepared statements are in the PHP code above as $big_query and $non_parameterized

Comment: Some further testing this morning revealed that integer types do not have this issue. I was able to bind 7000 integer types and the query ran in under 1/10th of a second.

Comment: I also ran the same setup under Python and am seeing the same problem.

Comment: @WormyGels  Have you considered using SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'  during your PREPARE step to avoid the possibility of invalid data values at run time?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I just set an environment to use the STRICT_ALL_TABLES flag and no effect on this parameterized query's runtime.

Comment: Runtime would not be affected, sending 'quoted' data when it should be integers should be stopped cold rather than taking extended wall clock time to completion.

Comment: MySQL 8 has no issue taking a string and comparing it to an integer
set @k = '7';
select 'true' as tf from (select 'test' as test) tbl where 7 = @k;

Comment: So, if you hard-code the parameters in PHP into the query, then it is having an acceptable performance, whilst if you bind your parameters to the query, then it's slow? Can you test the performance of `SELECT ?, ?, ?, ...` (many many parameters being binded to a trivial query)?

Comment: @LajosArpad I've done as you asked and that query executes in a reasonable amount of time. The placement of the bound parameters does seem to matter.

Comment: @WormyGels I know this seems to be unnecessary, but nevertheless, can you test the same parameterized query against the older MySQL? The reason for this question is that basically we just found out that the performance issue happens on PHP's end when it sanitizes the parameters. So, if the same slowness happens in the older version of MySQL, then the performance issue you found does not depend on the version of MySQL.

Comment: Why do you need to bind 7000 parameters in the first place? Where do they come from?

Comment: As a side note: your indices `a.name_id` and `c.product` are useless.

Comment: Question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989927/mysql-slow-execution-of-in-query-with-prepare-statement-after-upgrading-from-5-7).

Comment: @LajosArpad I've ran the above script in both version of MySQL and times are acceptable under 5.7. I've also ran a similar setup (parameterized query) in Python and am seeing the same behavior. It seems to be on the MySQL end as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are those all the columns in each table?  It would help if you used the real table names.

Comment: @RickJames The columns and table names I provided are enough to produce the slowdown. I just trimmed out all I could to see if I am still seeing the slowdown.

Comment: The `EXPLAINs` show only 1 row in each table?  Can you rerun them against fully populated tables; the query-plan may be different.

Comment: How many items in `IN(...)`?  There is a cutoff between leapfrogging versus a table scan.

Comment: Therefore,... Please `EXPLAIN` with 7000 items in the IN.

Comment: I reran the explain in JSON format. I thought the previous explains were ran against populated tables but the latest one I added certainly was.

Comment: `name` apparently changed from latin1 to utf8mb4, but I don't think this has any noticeable impact on perfromance.

Comment: The JSON EXPLAIN does not seem to agree with either of the non-JSON EXPLAINs.  How about updating all 4 Explains.

Comment: The binding could be a red hering. Could you test 2 specific execution plans with: `... inner join c force index (primary) on c.b_id = b.id and ...` and alternatively `... inner join c force index (b_id) on c.b_id = b.id and ...` (you have to add the `force index (xyz)` to your query).

Comment: DId you get to some conclusion? I am having performance problems as well when binding params. Although I think I might be into some improvements by changing from mysqli to pdo, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474564/mysql-query-performance-very-poor-when-using-php-mysqli-stmtbind-param-compa?noredirect=1#comment129790329_73474564

Comment: @G.Vescovi Nope, we were unable to figure this out.

Comment: Did you try to [submit a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/)? Given so many similar questions, it definitely looks like a bug, and you have a reproducible example that makes it legible.

Answer (score 0):

As another user previously mentioned, the default character set changes to utf8mb4 in MySQL 8.  Since you are using explicit utf8 charset definitions on some of the columns in the query predicate comparisons that are having issues, have you considered trying simply to "set names utf8;" in PHP?  With prepared statements, the coercibility of the parameters may be different than the coercibility of string literals.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33315103)

Answer (score -2):

`b` sounds like a key-value table, which is an inefficient anti-pattern.  But my point today is that 'normalizing' the `name` makes it worse.  Is table `c` a many-to-many mapping table?

So, get rid of table `a` and simply put the `name` in table `b`

There are some redundant indexes that you should Drop.

- In a table with `PRIMARY KEY(x)`, there is essentially no need for `INDEX(x, ...)`.
- With `INDEX(e, f), or` UNIQUE(e, f)`, there is no need to also have` INDEX(e)`.

**Key-Value**

```
CREATE TABLE FooAttributes (
    foo_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- link to main table
    key VARCHAR(..) NOT NULL,
    val ..., 
    PRIMARY KEY(foo_id, key),
    INDEX(key)    -- if needed
    INDEX(val)    -- if needed
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

- Normalizing the "key" value slows processing down without providing much space savings.
- The PK is designed for rapid access to the desired rows, hence,
- There no traditional `id AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- There is no clean solution when you need `val` to be either strings or numeric.

Comment: You're right `b` is a key-value table and `c` is a many-to-many mapping table. We've noted the redundant indexes but they don't have an impact on performance here.

Comment: I provided a better k-v template; work from it.  It should lead to better performance in _both_ servers.  With that change, the "50x slowdown" will probably go away.

Comment: @RickJames The table structure you're seeing is just a subset of our database. We have other tables referencing the primary key for `a` and denormalizing the table isn't a trivial undertaking or necessarily desirable within the context of our app.

Comment: @RickJames To be clear, are you saying you tested a new table setup with 7,000 mysqli bound parameters and didn't see the performance impact?